# VueJS get data as object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Here is a VueJS component:

```
<template>
  <a @click="log">click me<a>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        a: "a",
        b: "something",
        foo: { bar: "baz" },
        // etc.
      }
    },
    methods: {
      log() {
        // console.log( data ); 
        // ???
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

I want to access the `data` from the `log` function and get it as an object (just like in its declaration). I know I can get data like this :

```
log() {
  console.log( this.a );
  console.log( this.b );
  console.log( this.foo );
}
```

But what I want is the whole data as an object (because I want to send the data via an event to a parent component).

Is there a way to get the whole data object inside a method of a component?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can access the current component's data object using `this.$data`.

Reference: [Link](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-data)

So the log function should be like:

```
log() {
  console.log(this.$data.a);
  console.log(this.$data.b);
  console.log(this.$data.foo);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I think what you are looking for is to return the whole data object, like this:

```
log() {
  console.log(this.$data);
}
```