# Use axios with Vue and Laravel for post request

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to see Laravel + Vue but I have a problem on the vista side.
How can I send the data correctly through axios?
Look how I did it.

```
 <button onClick="addVote(question.id)">Vote</button>
data() {
            return {
              questions:[],
              percentages:[],
              vote:''
            }
        },
        methods: {
            getQuestions(){
                axios.get('/questionlist')
                    .then((response)=>{
                       this.questions = response.data.question
                    })
            },
            getPercentages(){
                axios.get('/getpercentage')
                    .then((response)=>{
                       this.percentages = response.data.percentage
                    })
            },
            addVote(id) {
                axios.post(`/vote/${id}`, data);
            }
        },
        created() {
            this.getQuestions(),
            this.getPercentages(),
            this.addVote()
        }
```

These are the methods in view to receive the data and send the data.
The last one is the voting method with which I want to send a request to the server and be able to add a + to each vote.

This is also the Controller

```
 public function vote($id) {
        $question = Question::find($id);
        if(Auth::user()->votes == 0) {
            $question->increment('votes', 1);
            $question->increment('totalvotes', 1);
            Auth::user()->update([
                'votes' => '1'
            ]);
            Alert::success("Success", 'Your vote has been added');
        }
        return response()->json($question);
    }
Route::POST('/vote/{id}',          'QuestionController@vote');
```

My question is, what am I not doing right in these situations?

Comment: `data` in `addVote` is undefined. You'd need to post `this.$data` if you want to do that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46091418/vuejs-get-data-as-object

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to add params in URL since it's POST request. You should use API routes (api.php) in Laravel and could structure it like this

```
Route::POST('/vote', 'QuestionController@vote');
```

Since you place it in api.php as API route, it would be prefixed with /api.
So you axios call should look like this:

```
addVote(id) {
            axios.post(`/api/vote`, {id: id});
}
```

Now in your vote method of QuestionController would look like this:

```
public function vote(Request $request)
{
    dd($request);
}
```

You will see dump of request data and decide what to do with it.

Comment: <button onClick="addVote(question.id)">Vote</button> I will get addVote() undefined